Нужна ли запятая перед что?

Мы что забыли закрыть дверь?

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед "что"? Если да, то почему, и чем это самое "что" является в предложении?

Вы точно имели в виду запятую перед "что", а не после "что"?

Да, я ошиблась)

Перед "что" не нужна, нужна после.
Мы что, забыли закрыть дверь?


Огромное спасибо!

Если ответ помог, нужно кликнуть по нижнему треугольничку!
